# Excel collapsing pivot table - or group weeks & months

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

What would be the best way to group information in excel by weeks and then by month. Basically I have this project where I am tracking what some sale advisors do within a week but then I'd also like to be able to group this information by month. 
Or I'd like to be able to create a pivot table that has an extendable button to search by week and person to view their KPI's.

I'm quite new so any help would be appreciated.

[image: photo of table]

Answer (score 1):

Enter real dates in the first column, and add the data into this flat table structure, i.e. date, agent, kpi values. No blank rows. Next week's data goes right into the next available row. Dates will repeat for each agent. Agent names will repeat each week.

Then you can build a pivot table with a few clicks. Dates can be grouped any which way, by day, week, month, quarter, year. Just right-click any date in the Pivot table and click Group, then select what you want to group on.

If you want to pivot and filter on specific KPIs, then you may want to use a data entry structure that has the columns date, agent, kpi type, value. You will then need one row of data for each combination of the fields, i.e. if you track four kpis per agent per week, there will be four rows per agent per week.

In the pivot table you can drag the kpi type into the columns area to see kpis side by side for each agent.